# Can I have meta data per field in Avro?

Tags: avro

Can I store some business metadata per field? other words, I have some business metadata I want to specify per field is that possible in Avro?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can add additional key-value pairs to a field. Quoting the [Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schemas):

> Attributes not defined in this document are permitted as metadata, but must not affect the format of serialized data.